# Whenever I try using tensorboard I get no module found error

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph, installation, tensorboard

When I run the command `tensorboard --logdir runs --hostlocalhost` on my windows I get an error like this
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorboard.main'; 'tensorboard' is not a package`

Answer (score 0):

As the error said,

> 'tensorboard' is not a package

It is python pacakge, so try to use python, for example:

```
python -m tensorboard --logdir runs --hostlocalhost
```

Edit: I found a tutorial [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tensorboard-tutorial#starting-tensorboard):

Make sure you already installed tensorboard

Comment: Yes, whenever I do that, I get the command accepted. But when I open the port nothing comes up. It just says web page cant be displayed

Comment: Then it's about your web page setting, it's not relating to this question.